# How to replace all escape sequence with blank in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have tried multiple things to convert my variable containing escape sequence characters into a blank string. How do I replace and escape sequence character with blank?

```
${stg}    Set Variable    \r\n
Replace String    ${stg}    \r\n    ${EMPTY}
Log     ${stg}
Should Not Be Equal    ${stg}    \r\n
```

In line 4, ${stg} == '\r\n'. How do I make this blank?

Answer (score 2):

You were very close,docs for Replace String gives you the answer:

```
        A modified version of the string is returned and the original
    string is not altered.

    Examples:
    | ${str} =        | Replace String | Hello, world!  | world | tellus   |
    | Should Be Equal | ${str}         | Hello, tellus! |       |          |
```

In your case,assign return of line #2 into ${stg}:

```
${stg}  Replace String    ${stg}    \r\n    ${EMPTY}
```